# javascript fixing canvas tainted in MDN example

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am working my way through [MDN Canvas tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial).

Working well until I get to Pixel manipulation, a color picker example.

getImageData gives:

> MDNTutorialBaseppp.html:21 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
>       at HTMLCanvasElement.pick

Here's the code I'm running:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
    <script>
      var img = new Image();
      //img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg';
      img.src = 'photo2.jpg';
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        img.style.display = 'none';
      };
      var color = document.getElementById('color');
      function pick(event) {
        var x = event.layerX;
        var y = event.layerY;
        var pixel = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
        var data = pixel.data;
        var rgba = 'rgba(' + data[0] + ', ' + data[1] +
            ', ' + data[2] + ', ' + (data[3] / 255) + ')';
        color.style.background =  rgba;
        color.textContent = rgba;
      }
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', pick);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Been beating on for several hours over several.

Can anyone spot the error of my ways.

Comment: Your image src is cross origin. Use your own same domain picture. Or even download that one and serve it locally.

Comment: Well, you just need to know what "cross-origin" means. You're probably not running your code on "mdn.mozillademos.org", so that means that the image is coming from a different origin. See [MDN's own article about the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image).

Comment: Downloaded the file locally and changed to local reference in code.  Same problem.

Comment: By "locally" what I mean is I have the html and image in a folder on desktop and double-click the html file.  Is that what you mean by "serve it locally," Jared or am I missing some basic concept here?

Comment: Thanks for reference, Heretic.  I'm pretty sure it has all I need to know on the topic.  But for someone struggling through the MDS tutorial, it's pretty intimidating.

Comment: Reading through the reference leads me to believe what I am doing, referencing everything locally, should work.  I have modified the code to reference photo2.jpg instead of the mdn image.  Both code and .jpg in same directory.  Any chance someone could run the code (supplying own photo2) either successfully or encountering the same error.

Comment: This will also not work - see how the file you opened has a protocol at the beginning looking like `file://`? That is _also_ considered cross origin by the browser. What I would suggest is either using an application like MAMP to run your own local web server, or use tools such as ParcelJS to serve your site while developing. This is _a lot_ to figure out, so for now I would suggest: install Parcel, run `parcel index.html` on that folder and see. It provides a dev server that runs locally as if its a real server, serving images and HTML as if connected to a real site on a single domain.

Comment: Or just do what I did and use your computer's built in python server (if running linux or macOS). But your code has several problems. That MDN canvas tutorial is written for Javascript developers who are new to canvas, not people with no coding experience. From your own link, emphasis mine: "Using the <canvas> element is not very difficult, *but you do need a basic understanding of HTML and JavaScript.*"

Comment: @JaredSmith I wasnt aware theres an easy built-in server. And diving in head-first could be a good way to learn - definitely if its just `canvas`. After the initial setup, playing around is quite painless. Also, I found this command to run from any folder to serve a folder as a site, I'm adding it for reference: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

Comment: Thanks JS & some...! Now beyond tainted to other issues.  I needed [additional info](https://1upnote.me/post/2019/02/set-up-local-http-server/) to let me understand I needed to access [http://localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000) to get at the html.

Answer (score 0):

The comments on this question provide an approach to working through this issue for the particular case presented.  You need to be running a local server which is easy to do.  The underlying issue is a complicated topic that I don't pretend to fully understand.